# Writing an long integer to an string as char* in Arduino function

Tags: c++, arduino, nodemcu

i am fighting with this problem for all night long, and nothing working for me...
I have tried with alot of methods founded on the internet, but i'm still locked here.

All I want is to write an number in the middle of an char string to display it on an oled screen using an nodemcu v3 based on ESP8266.
This is what I want to have on my screen: `S7:3.55V`

3.55 could be an number between 3.02 and 4.87.

Actual error is: `invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]`

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "OLED.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
        
OLED display(2, 14); //OLED Declarare SDA, SCL
long randNumber;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("OLED test!");

  // Initialize display
  display.begin();
  //display.off();
  //display.on();
  display.clear();
  delay(3*1000);
}

void loop() {
  randNumber = random(3.02, 4.87);

  display.print("S7:", 5);
  display.print(randNumber, 5);
  display.print("V", 5);
  //display.print("Banc: ", 7);
  //display.print(randNumber1, 7);
  //display.print("V", 7);
  delay(3*200);
}
```

Comment: please add a link to the OLED library. good libraries support printing numbers

Comment: Did you tried std::to_string()?  `display.print( ("S7:" + std::to_string(5)).c_str());` ?

Comment: @AdrianMaire is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is your friend here, write the number to a buffer first and then print that buffer. However you still need a different way to get to that number, `random` returns a long value, so to get your desired result you should adjust your parameters first:

```
randNumber = random(302, 487);
```

Don't worry about the decimals we'll get them back by appropriate formatting (in any case avoiding floating point entirely avoids at the same time quite a number of trouble mainly concerning rounding issues).

```
char buffer[16];
snprintf
(
    buffer, sizeof(buffer),
    "S7:%ld.%.2ldV", randNumber / 100, randNumber % 100
//      ^3^ ^55 ^    ^------ 3 -----^  ^----- 55 -----^
);
```

Now simply print out `buffer`...

Alternatives involve e.g. `std::ostringstream`, but these are not as convenient (and not as efficient) as good old C stdio API:

```
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << "S7:" << randNumber / 100 << '.'
       << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << randNumber % 100 << 'V';
print(buffer.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Thankyou buddy, it is amazing, i have spend over 12 hrs to get this work, i am working with web based codes, but there you have no problems with this kind of conversions...

Comment: can you explain me what represent "S7:%ld.%.2ldV" %.ld and %.2ld?

I want to work with example: S7:3.55V/S8:3.62V but i cant get it to work.

Comment: @MarcelDomuta See link in question: `%` introduces a format where a text will be inserted (`%%` inserts a percent sign) and the `d` signifies 'decimal output', if no length modifier is used an `int` has to be passed to. `l` is such a length modifier and tells the formatter the variable passed to is a `long int`. `.` introduces a precision and signifies for `int` how many digits to print at least (`%02ld` has similar meaning: align for two characters and use `0` as fill character; the result is the same then...).

Comment: @MarcelDomuta `"S7:%ld.%.2ldV/S8:%ld.%.2ldV", v1/100, v1%100, v2/100, v2%100`